# Avoid number of comparision for the following code program

Tags: java, loops, output

This was a question asked by my friend

Q))  Write the alternative coding using if statement so that it avoids number of comparison for the following code program

```
if(s==1)
System .out.println("One");

if(s==2)
System .out.println("Two");
if(s==3)
System .out.println("Three");
if(s==4)
System .out.println("Four");
if(s==5)
System .out.println("Five");
```

What i said was

to make it like this

```
if(s==1)
System .out.println("One");
else
if(s==2)
System .out.println("Two");
else if(s==3)
System .out.println("Three");
else if(s==4)
System .out.println("Four");
else if(s==5)
System .out.println("Five");
```

Is my answer correct ..But my doubt is in the worst case if s takes value 5 then this program has number of comparison same as the first case

is there any other ways by which i can further reduce the number of comparisons

Comment: Yes; use an array or map.

Comment: Use a list, map, or array, then you have no comparisons at all.